# Using kubectl run command equivalent with K8s Python client

Tags: python, kubernetes, client, kubectl

I have a K8s container running as `root`. I am trying to exec into the container with a `non-root` user using the K8s Python client. K8s [does not support](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30656) the feature to pass user flag to exec command as of today.

There is a hack to bypass this limitation using kubectl. The idea is to run a docker Pod on the same node as the target Pod. For more details, see this [tool](https://github.com/jordanwilson230/kubectl-plugins/blob/master/kubectl-ssh). The tool under the hood uses the `kubectl run command`.
Is there any way to get equivalent to run command using the Python client?

Answer (score 0):

kubernetes plugins are just scripts themselves, so you could in theory do something as simple as:

```
bash -x ./kube-ssh --option --option...
```

And watch as it runs the commands

Comment: I don't want kubectl dependency in the code. Is there any Pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Python does have a kubernetes client you can try: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python

Comment: Yeah, but it does not provide kubectl run equivalent through its Python API.

Comment: Since `kubectl run` creates a `Deployment` under the hood, you could just use the API to create that deployment directly? https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#create_namespaced_deployment